# Search from messages from user A AND/OR user B in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to search for messages from Jane or Bill in Outlook 2010. What is the syntax to do this on an advanced search? So far I have tried:

> from:Jane from:Bill

and that doesn't work.

Comment: "user A AND/OR user B" — emails can have two different *From* addresses? Or where does the *and* come in?

Comment: What word does the `/` between `and/or` represent? I realize this is grammatical semantics, but really you are searching for `A Or B` which is functionally equivalent to: `Only A`, `Only B`, `A And B`. Vernacular does not really have a place for an exclusive OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `from:(Jane) OR from:(Bill)`

Answer (score 0):

As well as William's answer you can open "Advanced Find" (inside the Search Tools dropdown) and add multiple contacts via the From: button

Answer (score 0):

You can also acheive this and much more complex queries by unlocking QueryBuilder in Outlook. This article describes the edits to the registry required to do this. It's about half way down under the heading "What's Next?". http://www.numanetworks.com/unlocking-the-potential-of-search-folders-in-outlook-2010/